# display equation in jekyll blog in latex format on github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, mathjax, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to write equations on my jekyll powered blog hosted on github pages. I am trying to use `MathJax` javascript library as per instructions [here](http://gastonsanchez.com/opinion/2014/02/16/Mathjax-with-jekyll/). Essentially, I added the following code below front matter in the `_layouts\page.html` and `_layouts\post.html`

```
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(copied from [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/extras/#math-support)). The problem is that the equations still do not show up correctly on the post, e.g., I wrote the following in my post (with a blank line above and below it):

```
[\\ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \\]
```

and instead of showing me the equation in the `latex` format on the page, it only escapes a `\` and shows me the following

```
[\ a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2} \]
```

Additional details (in my `_config.yml` regarding highlighting) are as follows

```
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
paginate: 5

kramdown:
   input: GFM
   hard_wrap: false
   # syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

Also, pasted below the is the code in `_layouts\page.html`

```
---
layout: default
---
<article class="post">

  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
  </header>

  <script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div class="post-content">
    {{ content }}
  </div>

</article>
```

and the code in `_layouts\post.html`

```
---
layout: default
---
<article class="post" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title" itemprop="name headline">{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p class="post-meta"><time datetime="{{ page.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">{{ page.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</time>{% if page.author %} • <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">{{ page.author }}</span></span>{% endif %}</p>
  </header>

  <script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div class="post-content" itemprop="articleBody">
    {{ content }}
  </div>

</article>
```

Any help in resolving this issues of showing equations properly will by very highly appreciated!

Thanks!

SN248

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the one hand, the math delimiters should be `\[...\]` (and double backslashes should you need to escape them).

On the other hand, kramdown (Jekyll's default markdown parser) has its somewhat unique math block syntax where it uses `$$...$$` for both inline and display style, cf. http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#math-blocks

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, `$$ ..$$` seems to work now. I had tried it before, and it wasn't but now the rendering is working.